# Get metadata from file .EPUB with Javascript

Tags: javascript, epub

Does anyone has implementing to get metadata from .EPUB extension with Javascript?
i have tried many ways, but its doesn't work. I need implement it directly not by backend javascript, such as Node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is of course what meta-data do you want to retrieve ?

There is a library called epub.js for the client side witch seems pretty friendly :

https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js

Take a look at the [Book.getMetadata()](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/tree/master/documentation#bookgetmetadata) in it's documentation.